# What is the meaning var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);?

Tags: javascript

What is the meaning of code in line 2 and 3 ? 
I want to understand it. Thanks.

```
   function stopRKey(evt) { 
      var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
      var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {
        addItemToList();
        return false;} 
    } 

    document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
```

Comment: Shorter: `evt = evt || event; var node = evt.target || evt.srcElement;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?:` is a ternary operator. Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

`var a = (b === true) ? 1 : 0;`

translates to

```
if (b === true)
    var a = 1;
else
    var a = 0;
```

`var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);`

means, if `evt` is truthy, `var evt = evt` (changes nothing).

If it's not, (`evt == null`, `evt === false`, etc.), assign it to `event` if `event` is truthy. Otherwise assign it to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
```

The above means:
If evt is true, evt remains true. Else if it is false, then check if event is true. It it is set evt to event if event is false, set evt to null.

```
var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
```

The above means
If evt.target is true, set node to evt.target else if it is false then check evt.srcElement. If it is true, set node to evt.srcElement if it is however false, set node to null

This type of code uses ternary operators.